# Mysql-stored procedure unable to feed data in table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Tables-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `brands`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brands` (
    `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
    `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `comment` text COMMENT 'USP for a specific category. Would be displayed on the webpages',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
    KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='List of all categories'
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `brand_category`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brand_category` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `brand_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `category_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `added` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `brand_name` (`brand_id`),
    KEY `brand_category_name` (`category_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `brand_category_name` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `brand_name` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brands` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Relations between brands and category';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `prices`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
    `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `price` float unsigned NOT NULL,
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `product_id_date` (`product_id`,`date`),
    CONSTRAINT `price_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Prices for products set on specific dates';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `brand_category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `model_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `video_url` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
    `display_name` text NOT NULL,
    `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `retail_price` float unsigned NOT NULL,
    `current_price` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `launch_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `brand_category_id_model_name` (`brand_category_id`,`model_name`),
    CONSTRAINT `product_brand_id` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_category_id`) REFERENCES `brand_category` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='List of all products available';
```

Mysql Stored procedure-

```
    DELIMITER //

    CREATE PROCEDURE `product_entry`(
        IN `category_name` VARCHAR(100),
        IN `brand_name` VARCHAR(100),
        IN `model_name` VARCHAR(255),
        IN `video_url` VARCHAR(150),
        IN `display_name` text,
        IN `description` text,
        IN `retail_price` float,
        OUT `category_id` tinyint(3),
        OUT `product_id` int(10)
    )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE brand_id smallint(5);
        DECLARE brand_category_id int(10);

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

        START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO categories (name)
        VALUES (category_name)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);

        SET category_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO brands (name)
        VALUES (brand_name)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);

        SET brand_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO brand_category (brand_id, category_id, added)
        VALUES (brand_id, category_id, CURDATE())
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);

        SET brand_category_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO product (brand_category_id, model_name, video_url, display_name, description, retail_price, launch_date)
        VALUES (brand_category_id, model_name, video_url, display_name, description, retail_price, CURDATE())
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);

        SET product_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO prices (product_id, price, date)
        VALUES (product_id, retail_price, CURDATE());

        COMMIT;

END//
```

I am executing the above procedure on the following tables. The first two queries in procedure are working properly, giving proper brand_id & category_id but queries for insertion of data in brand_category table, product & price table are unable to execute.

Comment: can you describe exact error ?

Comment: @Prince__ data are not getting feed in brand_category table, product & price tables. there is no as such error message.

Comment: A good idea when looking for errors is to not supress your error messages, so remove your error handler, and you will get them. One obvious error message that should appear is that you used the tablename `product` instead of `products`. And maybe the error why `brand_category` fails, not sure why, it looks fine to me. Though I think you might need a unique index for that two columns, although the missing index will not make your query fail. How did you check that the 2 inserts worked? Maybe they got rolled back too, but already had the data in it (you may want to add an "OUT success tinyint")

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for correction, its working fine now.